# How to add a html <a> tag with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done a slideshow for news on a website which works with jquery. Everything works perfectly except for a line where I try to add a link which links the complete version of the news. But Javascript never adds the tag nor show an error on the console.
Here's the function which changes the currently displayed news on the slideshow :

`function changeNews(newCurrentNewsNumber)
    {
        var realNewsNumber = newCurrentNewsNumber - 1;
        $("#number" + currentNewsNumber).css("color", "#FFFFFF");
        $("#number" + currentNewsNumber).css("backgroundColor", "#474747");
        $("#imageNews").attr("src").replace(newsImagePathArray[newCurrentNewsNumber - 1]);
        $("#number" + newCurrentNewsNumber).css("color", "#055c94");
        $("#number" + newCurrentNewsNumber).css("backgroundColor", "#FFFFFF");
        $("#textNews").html(newsTitleArray[realNewsNumber]+"<br />" + newsTextArray[realNewsNumber]+"<br />");
        $("#textNews").append("<a href=\"index.php?corps=news&id="+realNewsNumber+">Voir la suite de la news...</a>");
        currentNewsNumber = newCurrentNewsNumber;
    }`

newCurrentNewsNumber is the new news to display. currentNewsNumber is the old one. newsXXXArray contains elements of the news.
The line in blod is the one which doesn't do what it should. Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
$("#textNews").append("<a href=\"index.php?corps=news&id="+realNewsNumber+"\">Voir la suite de la news...</a>");
```

You just forgot to add an escaped " after '`+realNewsNumber+"`'
The devil **is** in the details

Comment: I think i found your real problem. Pls check again

Comment: Thanks, It works. What a stupid error ! I suppose it's the kind of problems you have when you work at 01:00am.

Comment: Lol.. been there myself.
btw. pls mark as answer if it helped:)

Comment: My original solution left out the escaped closing quote (though I edited back in).  Perhaps jQuery is smart enough to handle it?

Comment: Maybe JSFiddle is smart enough?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in JSFiddle:

```
function changeNews(newCurrentNewsNumber) {

    var realNewsNumber = newCurrentNewsNumber - 1;
    $("#textNews").html("Test Title"+"<br />" + "Text Text" +"<br />");
    $("#textNews").append("<a href=\"http://www.google.com?corps=news&id="+realNewsNumber+"\">Voir la suite de la news...</a>");
}

$(function() { changeNews(1); });
```

The only thing I can think of is you're trying to append the code before the DOM is completely loaded?